# Derive difference between two times in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, utc

I am extracting a time variable from the output of an API request and the output format is as follows.

```
> a
[1] "2019-09-06T09:03:14.938Z"
```

The first objective is to derive the difference with `Sys.time()`

```
> b<- Sys.time()
> b
[1] "2019-09-06 08:57:08 UTC"
```

I am having issues to run a basic `c = a-b`

```
> c<-a-b
Error in `-.POSIXt`(a, b) : can only subtract from "POSIXt" objects
```

When trying to convert `a` into a `POSIXT` object, I get the following error:

```
> c<-as.POSIXct.Date(a)
Error in unclass(x) * 86400 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The second objective would be to make the code wait until the time difference is possitive or zero. Maybe somethimg using `sys.sleep`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass proper `format` while converting into `POSIXct` object

```
a <- as.POSIXct("2019-09-06T09:03:14.938Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T")
```

and then do

```
b - a
```

You can also `difftime` which has `units` argument and can accept `"secs", "mins", "hours","days", "weeks"`

```
difftime(b, a, units = "mins")
```

---

Not exactly clear about the second part of the question however, we can write a `while` loop to make the code "wait" till time difference is positive or 0.

```
while(a > Sys.time()) { }
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the implementation with `base`. I will start from your suggestion with `while`

Comment: @GCGM No problem. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `lubridate` to convert strings into `POSIXct` objects, then you can subtract one from the other

```
library(lubridate)
as_datetime("2019-09-06 08:57:08 UTC") - as_datetime("2019-09-06T09:03:14.938Z")
Time difference of -6.115633 mins
```

To answer your second question (about waiting between API requests) `Sys.sleep()` is perfect for this

```
Sys.sleep(5) # sleeps 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you. It works percfectly but I prefer to use `base` fuctions to avoid installing extra packages in my script!